# Aligning more than 3 ChartAreas vertically

Tags: c#, vertical-alignment, mschart

I'm not able to align more than 3 charting areas in MSChart vertically without calculating position manually. Seems like MSChart decided that if you add more areas it would start aligning them horizontally.

I've tried playing around with ChartArea Alignment properties like Orientation, Style and AlignWithChartArea, but it would overlap areas one on the other if you try changing these.

So, has anyone tried working around this issue? The last thing I can think of is to calculate positions and align areas manually.

Thanks !

Comment: Take a look here http://support2.dundas.com/forum/tm.aspx?m=16997&mpage=1&key=&#16997

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working, but with this approach some of the useful chart properties cannot be used. In case of AlignWithChartArea MSChart is assuming that it has 2 rows and 2 columns (4 charting areas), so when I align all areas to first one and zoom-in - only first two sync X-axis visible view.

Comment: I was annoyed with the apparent lack of robust ChartArea Alignment that I just dynamically create new charts and "drop" them into a TableLayout control. This let me build up some nice MatLab like `subplot()` functions.